# How to execute code after LiveData's observers are all updated in Room Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am using Jetpack Compose with LiveData to show a list of items from an API. Now I got more or less a race condition which I have patched very ugly with multiple booleans, so I am wondering if there is an easier solution.

This is the problem:

- I got a LiveData object in a @Composable which holds the list of items
- When there are no items in the database and the API isn't loading, a text should be shown, indicating no items are shown. If the API call is not finished, a spinner is shown with a `MutableStateFlow` `Boolean` which knows if there is an ongoing call. This way there are 3 states.
- After my API call comes in, I do database changes and commit within a `runInTransaction` call. After that call, I change the `MutableStateFlow` `Boolean` value to false, indicating the Composable view should not show a spinner bar, but a list of items or a text when there are no items.

The problem is that after the `runInTransaction` call, the LiveData is not updated instantly, this is a problem because the API is finished loading and the `Boolean` is set to true, indicating it's done.

Even if I dispatch my code to update the boolean on the main thread after some milliseconds, I got no reliable way of executing code after my LiveData has finished updating the data with the newest data.

This results in the text showing very short that there are no items, followed by the list of items because the Composable view is lagging. I tried `refreshVersionsSync` on the invalidation tracker on the database, combined with a small delay and than set the `Boolean` to true, but even than that's quicker than the Composable being updated.

Is there any way I can know for sure the Livedata is/should be updating?